# Issue with MD5 hashing of image

Tags: c#, .net, hash, md5

I am trying to implement something really similar to  what RDP does, only I want to do my own implementation. The reasons don't matter.

For optimizations reasons I am dividing the screen in several blocks (100x100). So I only send the changed blocks to the client, and not the entire screen every time. To detect these changes on each block I am comparing MD5 hashes, the problem is that even though it is working several blocks are detected as changes, even though they are not changed. I can't understand why this is happening.

Below is the link to a debug image. See the highlighted areas, where there was detected changes and where there wasn't any changes detected.

[image]

This is the method that generates the hash for the image:

```
private static string GetMd5FromImage(Image image)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
                {
                    var computed = md5.ComputeHash(stream.ToArray());
                    var builder = new StringBuilder();

                    foreach (var t in computed)
                    {
                        builder.Append(t.ToString("X2"));
                    }

                    return builder.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

How could identical images generate the same hash? What am I missing?

Comment: Side note: I'd use raw image bits instead of checking hash of whole file (with headers/whatnot) and lossy compression...

Comment: So you are saying you would compare the entire data from the image?

Comment: You'd expect two identical things to generate the same hash, I'm assuming you meant to ask the inverse of that question?

Comment: No. What I meant is that I am taking screenshots of the same unchanged area of the screen, yet sometimes, the hashes are resulting different, for reasons I don't understand, yet.

Comment: Have you compared the actual values of the memory stream byte arrays before hashing them?

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I have 2560x1440 and was using 100x100 blocks resolution, which was causing each block resolution to be 25.6x14.4 (decimals). And that was causing the calculations of positioning to mess up. When changed to 10x10 (just for testing) it worked perfectly. I will make a method to find the maximum common multiple of each resolution.